# Update local storage using ngStorage in a generic function

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I am attempting to update local storage and I have downloaded and included [ngStorage](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage).

My app has two controllers -
 1. Handle filtering of a list to display search results
 2. Show recent clicks on results (derived from local storage).

Both controllers have a function in scope that collects the clicked element and then calls another function, passing the clicked element and the current local storage.  This function (below) should then update local storage, but I'm told that `localStorage.recentStations` is undefined.

I'm obviously missing something, but I'm not sure what?

```
function click_selectStation(localStorage, elm){
    localStorage.recentStations.unshift(elm)    // Add the most recent station to the beginning of the array
}
```

Here is my full code - http://pastebin.com/nvp1sHVq

Comment: do you have to use local storage, would a singleton factory not work?

Comment: `localStorage = $localStorage.$default..` will overwrite `window.localStorage` object since you aren't using `var`

Comment: @charlietfl - I added `$scope.` as opposed to `var`, but that was my problem.  Please post as the answer and I'd be happy to accept :)

Comment: @CallumLinington - I must confess I have no idea what a singleton factory is.  Any pointers to noob guides would bee appricated.

Comment: So a Factory allows you to basically create a singleton instance of a service. Because as the name suggests, it's a factory, so it should return an instance of a service. The lifetime should be the applications lifetime, where as localstorage far out lasts the applications lifetime

Comment: @CallumLinington - Thanks for the info, I'll have a look in to it, although I suspect it wouldn't be right for me in this instance as I need a list of recent users recent stations to be available everytime they return to the application.

Comment: fair enough, you could always have that stored on the server side, because then it would be *more* reliable

Comment: No server, this is an HTML/JS application that will eventually be wrapped as a applicatoin for Android deployment.